# Using vim with fish shell

Tags: shell, vim, fish

My vim powerline plugin is not displayed correctly when using fish shell.

[image]

When using bash, it displays properly:

[image]

I've tried adding `set shell=/bin/bash` in my `.vimrc` but that did not make any difference.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you set the shell before loading the plugin? Some more information would be nice, like a copy of your configuration.

Comment: @faho: Yes, I set the shell at the beginning of my `.vimrc`. The solution was to add `export TERM='xterm-256color'` to my `config.fish` but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to answer my own question.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question!

Comment: @Octi: Don't set it in fish, set it in your terminal - that way it'll work for all applications. Also I suggest not calling your TERM xterm unless it actually is - or is so compatible that it doesn't matter (and few things are).

Comment: I agree with @faho you should use the terminal capabilities to set TERM variable. For example, in xterm you can use the -tn argument or the termName resource (`man xrdb`).